# scrappy status page for failed spiders

Tags: django, web-scraping

I have made a spider to crawl the news and here is the code for that

```
class AbcSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 500]
name = 'abctv'
allowed_domains = ['abctvnepal.com.np']
start_urls = [
    'http://www.abctvnepal.com.np',
]

def parse(self, response):

    if response.status in self.handle_httpstatus_list:
        return Request(url="http://google.com", callback=self.after_404)

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) # The XPath selector
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="marlr respo-left"]/div/div/h3')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = NewsItem()
        item['title'] = escape(''.join(site.select('a/text()').extract())).strip()
        item['link'] = escape(''.join(site.select('a/@href').extract())).strip()
        item['description'] = escape(''.join(site.select('p/text()').extract()))
        item = Request(item['link'],meta={'item': item},callback=self.parse_detail)
        items.append(item)
    return items

def parse_detail(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    details = sel.select('//div[@class="entry"]/p/text()').extract()
    detail = ''
    for piece in details:
        detail = detail + piece
    item['details'] = detail
    item['location'] = detail.split(",",1)[0]
    item['published_date'] = (detail.split(" ",1)[1]).split(" ",1)[0]+' '+((detail.split(" ",1)[1]).split(" ",1)[1]).split(" ",1)[0]     
    return item

def after_404(self, response):
    print response.url
```

What i want is if the spider dont work or dont crawl then I want to show a status page saying spider is not working. How can I do that?? How can I make a status page ?? Any help ??

I have integrated this with django. Can I make a url in django for status then display. If yes then how

Answer (score 0):

I can only steps to take without providing any clear examples (better thank links anyway)

1. Create django project
2. Create single view in the project
3. This single view has to be able to somehow connect to your webcrawler :P. There are several ways of doing it:
4. Write some status updates into database (you can include your django project to python path and gain access to django orm in your crawler). You'll have to create models to hold the data, but that is not very hard.
5. You can use some kind of message queue (might want to check out http://www.celeryproject.org/). This might be the most complicated option as it requires setting up and configuring different software.
6. Or you could just check if your process is running by executing shell command in view and confirming if process of correct pid exists or not.
7. Return data based on approach 4. 5. or 6 from view.